# Ciclo para promedio con pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Buenas tengo el siguiente `df`, la cuestión es que necesito filtrar las velocidades por hora y con estas sacar un promedio, estoy utlizando el siguiente código:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv('df.csv')
b = df[(df['Fecha'] >= '2010-04-01') & (df['Fecha'] 
<= '2010-04-30') & (df['Hora'] == '22:00:00')]
c = b['Velocidad (m/s)']
d = np.nanmean(c)
```

Y quisiera saber si hay forma de poder hacer un `for` o algo similar que recorra todas las horas y no tener que estar cambiandolas manualmente.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ten cuidado cuando realizes comparaciones con cadenas que representan fechas como si lo fueran. La comparación se hace mediante orden lexicográfico, según que formato tenga la fecha podemos encontrarnos con resultados no deseados. Independientemente de lo anterior, parsear la fecha a `datetime` o `Datetimeindex`  te va a permitir usar muchos métodos asociados, por ejemplo agrupar por horas, meses, etc de forma simple, resampling...

Vamos a partir del siguiente DataFrame que es un ejemplo basado en el que muestras:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

csv = StringIO('''
Fecha,Hora,Velocidad (m/s)
2010-01-01,00:00:00,3.9
2010-01-01,01:00:00,4.2
2010-01-01,02:00:00,3.5
2010-01-02,00:00:00,2.5
2010-01-02,01:00:00,2.8
2010-01-02,01:00:00,3.4
2010-02-01,00:00:00,2.1
2010-02-01,01:00:00,1.6
2010-02-01,02:00:00,4.2
2010-02-02,00:00:00,2.5
2010-02-02,01:00:00,3.7
2010-02-02,02:00:00,3.2
''')


df = pd.read_csv(csv, dayfirst=True, index_col=0,
                 parse_dates = {'Fecha_': ['Fecha','Hora']}
                 )
```

Parseamos las columnas `Fecha` y `Hora` para agrupar ambas en un DatetimeIndex, el DataFrame que obtenemos es:

> ```
> >>> df
>                      Velocidad (m/s)
> Fecha_                             
> 2010-01-01 00:00:00             3.9
> 2010-01-01 01:00:00             4.2
> 2010-01-01 02:00:00             3.5
> 2010-01-02 00:00:00             2.5
> 2010-01-02 01:00:00             2.8
> 2010-01-02 01:00:00             3.4
> 2010-02-01 00:00:00             2.1
> 2010-02-01 01:00:00             1.6
> 2010-02-01 02:00:00             4.2
> 2010-02-02 00:00:00             2.5
> 2010-02-02 01:00:00             3.7
> 2010-02-02 02:00:00             3.2
> ```

Una vez que tenemos esto, dado que quieres obtener la media de cada hora por meses basta con usar `groupby`, agrupar por mes y por hora y aplicar `mean`:

```
medias = df.groupby([df.index.year,
                     df.index.month,
                     df.index.hour])['Velocidad (m/s)'].mean()

medias.index.names = ["Año", "Mes", "Hora"]
```

Con esto ya tenemos una Serie con las medias por hora de cada mes:

> ```
> >>> medias
>
> Año   Mes  Hora
> 2010  1    0       3.200000
>            1       3.466667
>            2       3.500000
>       2    0       2.300000
>            1       2.650000
>            2       3.700000
> Name: Velocidad (m/s), dtype: float64
> ```